# How can i refresh all Views in Database in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to refresh all views in Database because i renamed some columns and add some more columns in tables so i need to update all views by refreshing them

i created all views as `select * from tableName` only

Comment: I assume by "refresh" you mean "change the views so they now show the renamed/new columns"? No way to do that without an external tool or some sophisticated implementation. After all, how would the view *know* which of the new columns it should include?

Comment: You need to get a list of all views and call sp_refreshview for each one. But you should stop using * in  views.

Comment: Why did you bother creating views at all if they all all "select * from tableName only"? That defeats the purpose of views; you might as well select directly from the tables.

Comment: @DanGuzman select P.*, S.Col1, C.Col2 from PrimaryTable P (joined to) SecondaryTable S. First table is most of results, second table linked data. I do this ALL the time for search results and a column added to PrimaryTable will require a refresh. Concrete example - Person linked to Address.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for your response but below query fulfilled my requirement

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ActualView varchar(255)

DECLARE viewlist CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT
    DISTINCT s.name + '.' + o.name AS ViewName
FROM sys.objects o JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE   o.[type] = 'V'
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.[object_id], 'IsSchemaBound') <> 1
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.[object_id], 'IsMsShipped') <> 1

OPEN viewlist

FETCH NEXT FROM viewlist 
INTO @ActualView

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @ActualView
    EXEC sp_refreshview @ActualView

    FETCH NEXT FROM viewlist
    INTO @ActualView
END
CLOSE viewlist
DEALLOCATE viewlist
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Vie SYSNAME 
DECLARE cr CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT DISTINCT s.name + '.' + o.name 
    FROM sys.objects o JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id 
    WHERE   o.type_desc='VIEW'
OPEN cr

FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @Vie
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'exec sp_refreshview   '+''''+@Vie+''''
    EXEC ('exec sp_refreshview   '+''''+@Vie+'''')
    FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @Vie
END
CLOSE cr
DEALLOCATE cr
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

you can use this,

```
DECLARE @sqlcmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd +  'EXEC sp_refreshview ''' + name + ''';
' 
FROM sys.objects AS so 
WHERE so.type = 'V' 

--SELECT @sqlcmd     //**uncomment this line if you want to see all views names

EXEC(@sqlcmd)
```

Comment: This doesn't include the schema in the view reference (essentially ***assuming*** everything resides in the current schema or `dbo`), and it doesn't quote view names that need quoting (views named with space, for example, will cause this to error).

Comment: Even if there is space on the name of the view it will work, and on the other side he executes the query in the database where he wants to do the refresh

Comment: A database is not a schema!

Comment: I think that one of us did not quite understand his question (maybe me), otherwise it is that he has to make modifications on the columns of his database and he just wants to refresh his view, if he executes this query in his database it will do the trick.

Regards,

Comment: If in the database `x` and he creates a view `v`, that view can be addressed through `x.dbo.v` or `dbo.v` or just `v`. Your code does the latter. But, if they create a SCHEMA called `y` inside database `x`, and then create the view `v` there, it can be addressed through `x.y.v` or `y.v`, but not through just `v`. It will still be in the `sys.objects` as `v`, and so your code will try to address `v`, and error. You need to ALSO check `sys.schemas`, just like the Other Answer Here! Your answer DOES NOT RELIABLY WORK.

Comment: Look at this example...  https://dbfiddle.uk/_Oo_2AIj